How can I calculate sums of multiple columns without them being summed together into 1 column?
relatively new to R and am trying to solve an issue with my syntax.
I have a dataframe that looks something like this:
dat = tibble::tribble(
  ~Sample,  ~Motility,    ~Diet, ~Life.Position, ~n, ~t1, ~t2,~t3,
   '0m',     "Slow moving" ,   "Carnivore", "Infaunal", 1,3,1,5,
   '0m',     "Fac. mobile" ,   "Filter feeder", "Epifaunal", 2,1,1,3,
   '0m',     "Stationary attached", "Suspension feeder","Epifaunal", 1,3,4,2,
   '0m',     "Fac. mobile" ,  "Filter feeder", "Deep infaunal", 2,4,1,3,
   '0.5m',     "Slow moving" ,  "Carnivore",  "Infaunal", 1,3,1,4,
   '0.5m',     "Fac. mobile" , "Filter feeder", "Epifaunal", 2,0,1,1,
   '0.5m',     "Stationary attached",  "Suspension feeder", "Epifaunal",1,3,0,3,
   '0.5m',     "Fac. mobile",  "Filter feeder", "Deep infaunal", 2,4,2,3
   )


In reality, I have 18 different samples and I have 100 different t columns that represent subsampled abundance data for species appearing in my test samples.
I have tried a couple of things, though due to my inexperience likely not the correct way or the most efficient way.
I am trying to take all 100 subsamples and sum the same traits (motility, diet, life.position) within each column so I get this result:



Sample
Motility
n
t1
t2
t3
...




0 m
Slow moving
1
3
1
5
...


0 m
Fac. mobile
4
5
2
6
...


0 m
Stationary, attached
1
3
4
2
...


0.5 m
Slow moving
1
3
1
3
...


0.5 m
Fac. mobile
4
4
3
4
...


0.5 m
Stationary, attached
1
3
0
3
...



For example:
df %>%
   group_by(Sample, Motility) %>%
     summarise(trial = sum(across(t1:t100)))

This gave me 1 column with sums of each trait (nice) but summing all 100 trials together (not nice). I understand that a for loop  might be able to help me out however my understanding of them and their functionality is extremely poor.



Sample
Motility
trial




0 m
Slow moving
60


0 m
Fac. mobile
35


0.5 m
Slow moving
42


0.5 m
Fac. mobile
26


0.5 m
Stationary, attached
48



Any more information that you may need I can absolutely provide.
Thank you

@Axeman I must admit I didn't realize you could write it that way. That absolutely worked. Thank you so much.

@Axeman, post as answer (or, OP could post this as an answer once enough time has elapsed)

The across helper function can be used in this way:
df |>
 group_by(Sample, Motility) |>
 summarise(across(t1:t3, sum))


# A tibble: 6 × 5
# Groups:   Sample [2]
  Sample Motility                t1    t2    t3
  <chr>  <chr>                <int> <int> <int>
1 0 m    Fac. mobile              5     2     6
2 0 m    Slow moving              3     1     5
3 0 m    Stationary, attached     3     4     2
4 0.5 m  Fac. mobile              4     3     4
5 0.5 m  Slow moving              3     1     4
6 0.5 m  Stationary, attached     3     0     3


Another common way to tackle a problem like this, is to first use pivot_longer to change the data into "long" format, then summarise after:
df |> 
  pivot_longer(t1:t3, names_to = 't', values_to = 'value') |> 
  group_by(Sample, Motility, t) |> 
  summarise(sum = sum(value))

# A tibble: 18 × 4
# Groups:   Sample, Motility [6]
   Sample Motility             t       sum
   <chr>  <chr>                <chr> <int>
 1 0 m    Fac. mobile          t1        5
 2 0 m    Fac. mobile          t2        2
 3 0 m    Fac. mobile          t3        6
 4 0 m    Slow moving          t1        3
 5 0 m    Slow moving          t2        1
 6 0 m    Slow moving          t3        5
 7 0 m    Stationary, attached t1        3
 8 0 m    Stationary, attached t2        4
 9 0 m    Stationary, attached t3        2
10 0.5 m  Fac. mobile          t1        4
11 0.5 m  Fac. mobile          t2        3
12 0.5 m  Fac. mobile          t3        4
13 0.5 m  Slow moving          t1        3
14 0.5 m  Slow moving          t2        1
15 0.5 m  Slow moving          t3        4
16 0.5 m  Stationary, attached t1        3
17 0.5 m  Stationary, attached t2        0
18 0.5 m  Stationary, attached t3        3

